# Please Recommend Some Free ETL Tools

Tags: integration, database, cloud, etl

Can anyone recommend me some ETL tools to integrate salesforce with Oracle ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check on AppExchange and see if there are any tools available that matches your requirement.  However free tools might have few limitation when compared to paid version.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxSearchKeywordResults?keywords=oracle&price=free